# How can I completely uninstall SQL Server 2016 and everything that it installed?

Tags: uninstall, sql-server-2016

I installed the Express edition of SQL Server 2016 to test and I now want to uninstall it and everything that it installed on this server.

I have SQL Server 2014 installed and do not want that affected by the uninstall.

Am I safe to remove everything listed in Add/Remove programs with a certain installation date relating to SQL Server 2016, or would that affect the SQL Server 2014 installation also?

There doesn't appear to be a 'complete' uninstaller offered by Microsoft, and uninstalling the 'SQL Server 2016' leaves tons of other SQL Server 2016 related programs installed.